# How do I get Proton on Steam to work?

Tags: games, steam

I've heard about the new Steam Proton, but I have no idea how to get it to work. I'm obviously a newbie to Ubuntu and any help is appreciated! I followed the quick start on the Steam website and installed the NVIDIA driver.

What do I do?

Comment: Check this: https://steamcommunity.com/games/221410/announcements/detail/1696055855739350561

Answer (score 40):

You can activate Steam Play by doing:

1. Update **Steam** to the latest version.
2. Open **Steam** > **Settings**.
3. Go to **Steam Play**.
4. **Enable** all checkboxes.
5. Save the settings and restart Steam.

[image: Steam options page]

Comment: And what does this answer have to do with Proton? An answer should clearly answer the question.

Comment: <Proton is designed for integration into the Steam client as "Steam Play".> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_(software)